# Retornar um array de valores vindo de checkboxes para o controlador

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um problema a retornar os valores vindos das minha lista de checkboxes, o array "checkedcatequese" não chega ao meu controlador.

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[key]').change(function () {
            var key = $(this).attr('key');
            $($('[name="checkedcatequese[' + key + ']"]')).val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.catequizandoSessao)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                  @item.Nome
                                    <input type="hidden" name="pessoaid" id="pessoaid" value="@item.PessoaID"/>                                          
                                </td>                                             

                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" key="@i" />
                                    <input type="hidden" id="checkedcatequese[@i]" name="checkedcatequese[@i]" value="false" />
                                </td>                                                                                    
                           </tr>

                            i++;
```

Controlador:

```
   public ActionResult CriarAvaliacao(Avaliacao avaliacao,string[] pessoaid, string[] checkedcatequese)
        {

          //codigo

        }
```

Comment: Ainda assim não consigo resolver o meu problema